# Creating an object from a function adds unwanted key

Tags: reactjs, reduce

Hey I am not sure what is going on here. I know its probably something so obvious.

I have this bit of code in my reducer

```
const Dataformatter = (actionObject, data) => {

  return ({...actionObject, [`${data._id}-${data.positionId}`]: {
    status: data.tid.status,
    activatedDate: data.tid.activatedDate,
    stage: data.name,
    details: data.tid.details,
    submitted: data.submitted,
    taskHistory: data.tid.taskHistory,
    totalStepsInTask: data.totalStepsInTask,
    positionOfAction: data.positionOfAction,  
  }})
}

const actionReducer = (state, action) => {


  switch (action.type) {
    case "INIT_ACTIONS":
  
    console.log(action.actionData)
      let actionObject = {};
      action.actionData.map((data) => {
        actionObject =  Dataformatter(actionObject, data)
      });

    return actionObject;

    case "ADD_ACTION":

    const addedAction = Dataformatter({}, action.actionData)
    return {...state, addedAction }
```

The goal here is having the function Dataformatter to create the correct formatted object for boht the INIT_ACTIONS and ADD_ACTIONS cases (Save duplication of code).  INIT_ACTIONs is working fine.

However,  ADD_ACTIONS code WAS working fine but now its doing something odd.

Rather than adding the new data in the form created by the dataformatter function it adds it with object key of "addedActions: data as per dataformater".

**Output in console log of state**

```
6380259267885e98ca349938-6380259267885e98ca349936-1: 
{status: 'In Progress', activatedDate: '2022-11-25T02:16:50.588Z', stage: 'Design', details: {…}, submitted: false, …}
addedAction: {63812949d5cf2ce2cf32284a-63812949d5cf2ce2cf32
```

How do I adjust it so it adds the data as per dataformatter and not use addedAction as the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this solves your problem `return {...state, ...addedAction }`.

And I'm not sure but I think this may also work:

```
case "ADD_ACTION":
    return Dataformatter(state, action.actionData);
```

Comment: Thank you!. I knew it would be something so obvious and simple I was missing. That worked a treat.